# SharePoint column color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add background colour to a particular column in a SharePoint list, which is a drop-down.
The cback ground colour should be green if the grade is A and so on for different grades
I found code online but that causes changes in the colour of other columns which even have A.

Any help is appreciated and apologies that I cannot add sample code that I am using currently.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not able to add the code that you've tried to the question? It would really help people to see what your issue is in greater detail.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes what happens is, the code is applied to <td> tag with the class name, so when I apply the code every other column containing the same values is coloured. The code is something like below

$(document).ready(function(){
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Yes')");
$Text.css("background-color", "green");
$Text.css("font-weight", "A");
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('B')");
$Text.css("background-color", "red");
$Text.css("font-weight", "bold");
});
so this causes all other columns having A also get colored